# Security in Restful web application in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I am working in restful web services . We are creating web services which is running in glassfish and we are calling these restful web services directly from our jsp deployed in tomcat . I have to make our web service secure such that no other person or organisation can hit(use) our web services from there application . Can you tell me how to do these ??????

Comment: Search for make a login in rest...

Answer (score 1):

one easy way is to transmit [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) information in every rest request and intercept each request on your rest backend. in your interceptor you try to get these information and check in your database if these information is correct.

to parse the auth information from your header do the following:

```
            // Get request headers
            final HttpHeaders headers = request.getHttpHeaders();

            // Fetch authorization header
            final List<String> authorization = headers.getRequestHeader(AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY);
            // Get encoded username and password
            final String encodedUserPassword = authorization.get(0).replaceFirst(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " ", "");
            // Decode username and password
            String emailAndPassword;
            try {
                emailAndPassword = new String(Base64.decode(encodedUserPassword));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return SERVER_ERROR;
            }

            // Split username and password tokens
            final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(emailAndPassword, ":");
            final String email = tokenizer.nextToken();
            final String password = tokenizer.nextToken();
```

now you can use the Strings email and password as credentials that you can check against your database.

remember you must do this for every request before it reaches your webservice implementation. you should read about interceptors for this matter

regards